# How to write an ISPICKVAL formula

Tags: formula-field

I have one picklist field that contains "Signed", "sent" and "received".
I would like to create a text formula field that displays "in progress" if "Signed" or "Sent" have been selected. Or "Complete" if "received" is selected. However, I'm having trouble with the formula. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community.  You should use [edit] and show what you've tried.

Comment: Can you please share the formula which you have written?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`CASE`](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_case.htm&type=5) function here which means you won't need to use `ISPICKVAL`. Your formula would look like this:

```
CASE(Picklist_Field__c, 
    "Signed", "In progress", 
    "Sent", "In progress", 
    "Received", "Complete", 
NULL)
```

- The first parameter is the field name you're checking
- Then you have pairs of the value you're checking and the value you want your formula to take
- Then finally the value you want when your field matches none of the options

Comment: N.B. I prefer `NULL` as value of otherwise

Comment: Good idea, I'll change it